# Tailwind flex container not showing overflow in X axis, why?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css, overflow

I am a bit confused about the way this code works. I am new to tailwind and I don't know if I am missing something important, but a simple code that pretends to display a couple of elements horizontally inside a div, and pretends to generate overflow in both X and Y axis, only appears to be working on the Y axis and I don't understand why. I tried it in vanilla HTML/CSS and it worked as expected, but not in TailwindCSS.

Anyone can try it in the Tailwind Playground (https://play.tailwindcss.com/), just paste the code and you'll see that the overflow only appears in the Y axis, but not in both as I would want to. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="flex h-[400px] w-[1000px] gap-24 overflow-auto">
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to share the actual `css` and not just the class names.

Comment: @ToniWidmo there is no custom css for these classes, it is pure Tailwind styles.

Answer (score 0):

you can play with length and width to find out overflow-x and overflow-y

```html
<div class="flex h-[400px] w-[1000px] gap-24 overflow-auto">
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
</div>
```

if you confused about the overflow, you can read this:

[overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.php)

[overflow-x](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.php)

Answer (score 0):

This code block could fix your issue as per your requirement.

```html
<div class="h-[400px] overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="flex w-[1000px] gap-24 overflow-x-auto">
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The outer div has a fixed height of 400px and allows vertical scrolling (`overflow-y-auto`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            clifford: '#da373d',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

<div class="h-[400px] overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="flex w-[1000px] gap-24 overflow-x-auto">
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
    <div class="h-[600px] w-[500px] rounded-2xl bg-sky-300/40"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**1.** Used overflow-y-auto on the outer div to allow vertical scrolling.

**2.** Used flex and overflow-x-auto on the inner div to allow horizontal scrolling for child elements that exceed the container's width.

> [Try it](https://play.tailwindcss.com/t7xQvFMsf3)

Comment: Oh I see... I thought it would be possible to get the job done in one unique div. I understand the way you made it and it makes full sense to me. Thank you so much!